# Brain cell temperature

Tags: neuroscience, measurement, cognitive-modeling

Given: a brain cell has an average temperature,  T.

If: 
perpetual brain activity pattern, X ; 
has an average conductive resistance, R;

Therefore:
Could it be rationally assumed that activity pattern X, increases T, by a factor of R?

Comment: Most likely nobody knows.

Comment: The brain waves you refer to are actually not actual waves from the brain. Instead, they are the result of mathematical decomposition of raw data and I don't believe you can link warmth production with those. It may be easier to ask/answer how much energy is consumed during (or after) an action potential in one cell/network of cells, when pumps distribute sodium, calcium and potassium.

Comment: As @RobinKramer points out, this question does not make much sense. Brainwaves do not have a temperature, as they are voltage differences. For what its worth - photons lack a temperature. In general, a physical body with a defined mass can have a temperature, and hence, afaik, radiation lacks a temperature. However,a related question on [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59456/the-temperature-of-photon-and-its-energy) goes into more detail on radiation and temperature and states that some radiation can be assigned a temperature. In all, I vote to close as question is unclear

Comment: You just blew my mind , I didn't know photons that photons lack temperature. You're right my question makes no sense. I'll see if I can wrap my head around it in the physics section. Thanx

Comment: @RobinKramer you bring up an interesting approach in terms of measuring the cells energy consumption, can it be then safely assumed that different brain cells can produce and consume different amounts  of heat energy transfer?